# Does Windows or Linux have any tools for accessing a FileVault2 encrypted drive's contents?

Tags: windows, filevault, unix, mount

I'm looking to mount (and access files on) my FileVault2 encrypted drive on a non-OS X box, and am wondering if anyone has done this with Windows or Linux.

Comment: There is this project on Google Code : https://code.google.com/p/libfvde/ But some how I can't find the sources anymore.

Comment: I see there is a less than visible "external download" link on that page (bottom of left column) with the source code: https://googledrive.com/host/0B3fBvzttpiiSLUVJYl9XRWhKSjg/  -- I emailed the developer to inquire about status of project, so will reply back if he says anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, the [libfvde](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde) project aims to support decoding FileVault2. Yogesh Khatri wrote an [overview article](http://www.swiftforensics.com/2013/03/decrypting-apple-filevault-full-volume.html) where he suggests starting with [libfvde's wiki](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki).

On Windows, the company Passware claim support for decrypting FileVault2 drives as part of [Passware Kit Forensic 13.1](http://www.lostpassword.com/kit-forensic.htm). A [CNet article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57369983-263/filevault-2-easily-decrypted-warns-passware/) mentions the software and highlights the feature in an included screenshot:

[image: Passware Kit Forensic]

Comment: that a $1K+ piece of software...

Comment: Yes, Passware are currently charging 1095 euros for their work; for some this will be good value.