# Encrypt External Hard Drive for Mac and Linux

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, filevault, encryption

I have an external hard drive that I backup with Time Machine. I'm trying to determine the best way (or if it's even possible) to encrypt it so that Time Machine can still back it up and it can be mounted and read by my Ubuntu server. I'm not hoping for write access but that'd be even better.

I've looked into way to read File Vault 2 volumes on Ubuntu but haven't found anything too promising. So I'm assuming I need to go with something like TrueCrypt but am not sure how Time Machine will handle that.

The driver is currently formatted with OS X extended but I can format if needed.

Comment: Nothing I've found yet, but here's an interesting project to keep an eye on: http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Open-source-tools-for-accessing-FileVault-encrypted-Macs-1664441.html

Comment: Is the goal to [have ubuntu read the content that's backed up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272351/how-to-mount-apple-core-storage-partition) or just have two uses co-exist sharing sections of the drive? (each is quite different in implementation)

Comment: @Crystalclaw thanks, that does look like what I need. Hopefully they can get it worked out. By the way, all the links from h-online.com seem to be broken; looks like they've moved to Github: ttps://github.com/libyal/libfvde

Comment: @bmike the latter. I'd like to have just one partition on the drive that's read by both systems and backed up by Time Machine (and encrypted).

Comment: Yeah - it looks like the code is taken down - I didn't try searching archive.org - but it looks like it wasn't out for that long or that "done" - If I find an alternative, I'll pop back with more details.

Comment: Better question: can you leave the drive plugged into the ubuntu machine and do backup over the network? If so, I have a solution, if a bit hacky.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle this situation is to buy a drive that uses OS-agnostic hardware encryption, then format it with a format which is readable by both OS X and Linux. Since both Time Machine and Ubuntu are referenced, you may want to install `hfsprogs` in order to enable Ubuntu to read OS X's HFS+, then format the drive itself as HFS+:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/otherosfs/hfsprogs

Answer (score 0):

The same question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108576/does-windows-or-linux-have-any-tools-for-accessing-a-filevault2-encrypted-drive) was answered with [this library on GitHub](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki) for decrypting FileVault 2 drives on Linux.

As for actually encrypting the drive, you can do so by right-clicking (or control-clicking) the drive's entry in the sidebar (under "Devices"), and choosing "Encrypt [driveName]…". It will ask for a password (entered twice) and a password hint.